# External program searching DOORS data

Tags: ibm-doors

I'm a programmer on a moderate ASP.NET C# project.  We've been given a requirement to integrate our application with a DOORS installation.  Specifically, from our app the user wants to be able to search in DOORS for relevant objects and provide links to them.  I'm not a DOORS expert by any means, and I've been having a "glorious" time trying to figure out how to do this.  From what I can tell, there are three different ways to access the DOORS data outside of the DOORS client:

1. DXL
2. DOORS Web Access
3. OSLC

The impressions I've gotten from my search are these:

1. DXL might be the best solution--seems to be a moderately powerful scripting solution
2. Web Access doesn't seem to be very well-documented.  Maybe it's just a fancy term for a web-based access system that is wholly dedicated to realizing the normal client operations inside a browser.  Perhaps I could hack my application to replace the browser and use that type of access to search and show results?
3. OSLC seems to be just a way of linking DOORS artifacts to outside systems.  This might suffice if it includes an interface to the search capabilities.

So, what might be the best approach?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Option 1:

DXL can do what you need, you would however be running a DOORS Client in batch mode. So wherever you are running this integration from must have a DOORS client installed and the integration script you write must have login information (username and password). This can be encrypted in a separate file using a dxl encryption utility that should still be available on IBM developerworks or on google. This is definitely your most flexible option as DXL is very powerful. Search `batch` in the DOORS DXL Help inside the tool and you should have all the information you need about running a DXL script in batch mode.

Option 2 and 3:

These options are actually related. You would not integrate to DOORS using DWA through a web browser, but in order to use OSLC you must have a DWA web server installed. OSLC communicates to DOORS through the DWA server. OSLC would be able to get you what you need, but this route is probably more difficult and less flexible.

Hope this helps.

Comment: What about creating HTTP services using DXL? 
We again have to struggle with DXL in order to get resources, you have to write everything you need from XML parser, logging and so on you have limitations like passing only one string as input paramter, you have to log in the DWA to get the access token, but can create flexible services. Is that better approach than just execute scripts?
Also I see that there is some Java API provided by SOdius. Are thir using better?

Answer (score 0):

Correct but,
dxl scripts are IBM's mean of extending the OSLC framework.

You might execute dxl scripts with out having to install/run the batch client from within your integration, you can use the dwa/oslc/dxl/yourdxlscriptname urn inorder to execute the script for you.

The only 'issue' with this, is that the Doors Admin MUST register your dxl script with the list of available executable scripts.